# Saraswati mantra for students who have lost concentration in studies

Tags: mantras, identification-request, saraswati

There is a 2 line Saraswati mantra and the first word is very long and it starts with 'k'. This is all I know about the mantra. Can someone guide what is the mantra, its meaning, and in which book it's in?

Comment: Mantras usually start with Om .. are you sure it starts with K? Or the first word after Om starts with K?

Comment: Or may be you are talking about a Shloka and not Mantra because it is formed with 2 lines?

Comment: is it ' yA kundedutuSharhar dhawala ...', a simple google search will give it

Comment: Possibly 'yākundēndu tuṣārahāradhavaḷā yāśubhravastrāvṛtā'. I have not heard anything about it helping one regain concentration, however.